# Display of HeaderText in GridView

Tags: gridview, headertext

I am currently working on making webpages ADA compliant. 
I have a column in gridview that basically has Update/Delete links , so it does not have a header displayed.

But for ADA compliance, I need to have some text so that screen readers can properly interpret the grid header.
I tried:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" ShowHeader="False">
```

but does not seem to work.

Any solutions?

Comment: set `ShowHeader` to true.

Comment: I do not want to show the header text, but say for a visually disabled person, screen reader should read the header text saying what the column is